# How to find the distribution?

Tags: distributions

If $ L=2Y_1 +3Y_2 −2Y_3 \ \text{and} \  Y_i \sim N(\mu=1,\sigma=1)  $

I'd appreciate any tips on how to find the distribution of this.

Comment: Is it a homework problem? If yes, it should be tagged `[self-study]`, see the [tag:self-study] wiki.

Comment: Are $Y_i$s mutually independent?

Comment: @Luca, yes, they are.

Comment: Where do you get stuck in this derivation?

Comment: You should look up for the formula on sums of independent normal variables.

Comment: This site contains *many* worked examples of precisely this kind of question.  See our site search applet in the upper right corner of every page.

Answer (score 1):

Linear combination of Normal Random Variable is also Normal Random Variable.
$$E(L)=2E(Y_1) +3E(Y_2) −2E(Y_3)=2+3-2=3$$
$Cov(Y_i,Y_j)=0~for~i\neq j$
$$Var(L)=2^2Var(Y_1) +3^2Var(Y_2) +2^2Var(Y_3)=2^2+3^2+2^2=17$$
Hence, $$L\sim N(3,17)$$

Comment: Please consult our [tag:self-study] wiki for guidance on how to respond to routine textbook questions.  In particular, we prefer not to provide complete answers to obvious homework problems.  Since most such problems have already appeared here, it is *much* more useful to our site to provide a link to an existing solution and vote to close the question as a duplicate.